# programming with ggplot using aes_ or aes_string with special characters in column names

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, aesthetics

I need to run ggplot in a function. The input data.frame/tibble passed to the function has special characters (white spaces, commas etc.) in the columns with data to be plotted. The column names to be plotted are passed as arguments to the function. Here is a working example, both aes_ and aes_string fail, but for different reasons. Help appreciated

```
trial.tbl_df <- tibble(a = 1:3, `complex, `=4:6)

plotfunc <- function(tbl2plot,yvar){

  ggplot(tbl2plot,aes_(x = "a", y = yvar )) + 
    geom_point()

}

plotfunc(tbl2plot = trial.tbl_df, yvar = `complex, `)
```

Comment: I'm using R version 4.1.1 and ggplot2_3.3.5

Comment: Note that `aes_` and `aes_string` are both soft-deprecated in `ggplot2`, I suggest you look into programmatic quasi-quotation methods. Look for tutorials on "tidy evaluation", such as https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

Answer (score 1):

As @r2evans mentioned, you can use [tidy evaluation](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/) as `aes_` and `aes_string` are deprecated:

```
trial.tbl_df <- tibble(a = 1:3, `complex, `=4:6)


plotfunc <- function(data, y){
  
  y <- enquo(y)

  ggplot(data, aes(x = a, y = !!y)) + 
    geom_point()
  
}

plotfunc(data = trial.tbl_df,  y = `complex, `)
```

Answer (score 1):

`aes_` and `aes_string` both are used when you pass column names as string. Since both of them are deprecated you can use `.data`.

```
library(ggplot2)

trial.tbl_df <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:3, `complex, `=4:6)

plotfunc <- function(tbl2plot,yvar){
  
  ggplot(tbl2plot,aes(x = a, y = .data[[yvar]])) + 
    geom_point()
  
}

plotfunc(tbl2plot = trial.tbl_df, yvar = "complex, ")
```

[image]

PS - Not sure why you have such *complex* name for the column instead of standard one.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `aes_` and `as.name`:

```
trial.tbl_df <- tibble(a = 1:3, `complex, `=4:6)

plotfunc <- function(tbl2plot,yvar){
  
  ggplot(tbl2plot ,aes_(x = ~a, y = as.name(yvar))) + 
    geom_point()
  
}

plotfunc(tbl2plot = trial.tbl_df, yvar = "complex, ")
```